# Why isn't Anime and Manga included in the Winter Bash like other BETA sites?

Tags: support

I've seen other sites (such as [Movies and TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/)) which are participating in the Winter Bash (and hats and whatnot).

Why isn't this site part of it too?

[image: Movies and TV - Winter Bash]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a lot of lead time in preparation of this year's Winter Bash event, including the coordination of 90+ sites for discussion of whether they wanted to opt in or not.

The Anime SE site went public only recently… too late to be included in this year's event. Watch for future events; you will not be excluded!

Comment: Thank you! Could you come to chat? I have several more things I'd like to ask our community coordinator :)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha It would be difficult to coordinate a real-time collaboration like that. Feel free to shoot me an email.